# Openlayers 3 - ScaleLine text formatting

Tags: text, scale, openlayers-3

Is there a way, how to change ScaleLine text? When I choose 'nautical' units, miles are shown as nm instead of NM.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to customize the output of the ScaleLine control. You could write your own control, or modify the DOM element after it's rendered.

However, since all you want is for it to be uppercase, you could use CSS:

```
.ol-scale-line {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```